# Why does Plot try symbolic values?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
Test[a_] := (Print[a]; a*2)

Plot[Test[a], {a, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

This should plot `a*2` for five points between `a = 0` and `a = 10`, and print whatever `a` is every time `Test[a]` is evaluated. Indeed, that's exactly what it does, and this is the output:

```
0
0.0025025
a
2.5*10^-6
2.40451
5.01127
7.44529
10.
```

Most of this is pretty reasonable - I'd expect `Plot` to try 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, and 10 - but why is `a` a value that `Plot` tries? It's symbolic, so I don't see why it would ever be used in a plot.

Moreover, if I change `Test` so that it returns `Null`:

```
Test[a_] := (Print[a]; a*2;)

Plot[Test[a], {a, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

`Plot` no longer tries any symbolic values at all:

```
0
0.0025025
2.40451
5.01127
7.44529
10.
```

It also no longer tries `2.5*10^-6`, though I'm not sure if that's related.

What's going on here? Why is `Plot` trying symbolic values (and why doesn't it do this when my function returns `Null`?)

edit: To clarify, this is a minimal working example. I don't actually want to print out the values as a side-effect. I have a compound expression that finds some value I care about and returns that, and when I try and plot the result for different values, it breaks due to having a symbolic variable passed in.

Another trivial example of code that does this, as requested in the answers:

```
Test[a_] := (
  val = Sqrt[a];
  Print[a];
  solution = val*2;
  solution)
```

The `Print[a];` line is only here to show the values of `a`; this behaviour still occurs when I delete that line.

Comment: Just use '?NumericQ' pattern test on argument(s) to prevent this causing issues w/ your function... I'm sure others will post details (I'm mobile, so terse...)

Comment: I did try that, but I still get errors for some reason. It continues to evaluate anyway, and I get errors turning up with `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the symbolic evaluation occurs as part of exclusions detection. If you evaluate the plot with `Exclusions -> None` the symbolic evaluation doesn't occur.

I suppose when you use a function which returns a non-numeric result such as Null, the system skips the exclusions detection altogether.

Comment: Ah, this solves the immediate problem! Thanks!